# Problem when i check update!

Tags: updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

When i try to check updates comes

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kayo-k11-4/nv-switcheroo/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kayo-k11-4/nv-switcheroo/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What i must do?

Answer (score 0):

remove this repository from your sources: go to `System Settings` then `Software Sources` then look for this repository under `Other Software`

(if it is not immediately obvious, you may have to click `Edit` to see the URL of each repository in that list)

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the ppa at http://ppa.launchpad.net/kayo-k11-4/ you will see the nv-switcheroo ppa does not have a binary for oneiric. You can either remove that repository as mentioned by totaam or fix it to point to the existing maverick source. If you need help with that, note a comment and I'll point you in the right direction since it changed in oneiric.